# validate every fields changes in domain class

Tags: java

I have domain class which contain following fields

```
private long id;

private String questionNo;

private byte[] question;

private byte[] option1;

private byte[] option2;

private byte[] option3;

private byte[] option4;

private String answer;

private byte[] explanation;

private Topic topic;

private Chapter chapter;

private Subject subject;
```

in my controller class i want to validate every fields changes for updating purpose.

I already tried

```
0 = 'success'
1='No Change'
2='Question No Already Exists'


public int validateQuestion(Question question){
        Question questionForCheckNo=questionService.findQuestionByQuestionNo(question.getQuestionNo());
        Question existingQuestion=questionService.findById(question.getId());
        if (existingQuestion != null
                && ((question.getSubject().getId() == existingQuestion
                        .getSubject().getId())
                        && (question.getChapter().getId() == existingQuestion
                                .getChapter().getId())
                        && (question.getTopic().getId() == existingQuestion
                                .getTopic().getId())
                        && (question.getQuestionNo().equals(existingQuestion
                                .getQuestionNo())) 
                        && (question.getAnswer()
                        .equals(existingQuestion.getAnswer()))
                        &&(question.getIsMock()==existingQuestion.getIsMock())
                        &&(!Arrays.equals(question.getQuestion(), existingQuestion.getQuestion()))
                        &&(!Arrays.equals(question.getOption1(), existingQuestion.getOption1()))
                        &&(!Arrays.equals(question.getOption2(), existingQuestion.getOption2()))
                        &&(!Arrays.equals(question.getOption3(), existingQuestion.getOption3()))
                        &&(!Arrays.equals(question.getOption4(), existingQuestion.getOption4()))
                        &&(!Arrays.equals(question.getExplanation(), existingQuestion.getExplanation()))

                )) {

           return 1;
        }
        else if(questionForCheckNo!=null){
            return 2;
        }



        return 0;
    }
```

calling this function every time it will return only '1'.even if i change byte array field.

But everything else is working great.

Comment: Debugger will help you.

Comment: i tried with my remote debugger..no change

Comment: questionService.findQuestionByQuestionNo(question.getQuestionNo());
questionService.findById(question.getId());
what this two methods will returns?
can you enplane @jijishvu07

Comment: the 2 line are working fine..error may be on if conditions.
the first line for find question by question no a unique result.
the second line is for find by id question.

Comment: Based on the code, it should work :). A wild guess - is it possible that the byte arrays are not initialized/not properly transferred/not serialized and end up being NULL?

Answer (score 0):

You have issue with `!`

```
!Arrays.equals(question.getQuestion(), existingQuestion.getQuestion())
```

When you change array `Arrays.equals()` return `false`, But `!false` will convert it again to `true`.

So you will get `1`

Comment: Actually i get 1 every time even if i change my fields.
Both tried with '!' and without.